# strftime %l gives error

Tags: python, time

I'm trying to make a simple clock and I want the format to have the numeric hour without a padding zero. According to every source I can find on google the symbol for that is %l but that gives me a traceback error? It works fine if I use %I though.

```
def count():
    global time1
    global date1
    time2 = time.strftime('%l:%M %p')
    date2 = time.strftime('%A, %B %d %Y')
    if time2 != time1:
        time1 = time2
        clock.config(text=time2)
    if date2 != date1:
        date1=date2
        date.config(text=date2)

    clock.after(500, count)
```

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "D:/Program Files (x86)/pycharm/Projects/test.py", line 48, in count
       time2 = time.strftime('%l:%M %p')
ValueError: Invalid format string

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I think it's `%-I`. (Capital i, not an L.) See http://strftime.org/.

Comment: The format in your code looks like a small 'L' to me.

Comment: Could you provide all your imports for this example in order to run your code?

Comment: I only have time and tkinter imported

Comment: I tried %l (lowercase L) and %-I (uppercase i) but neither worked

Answer (score 0):

You want `%-I`:

```
time2 = time.strftime('%-I:%M %p')
```

http://strftime.org/ is a nice reference for Python's `strftime` format strings.

Comment: I did that but now it says
ValueError: Invalid format string

Comment: Can you update your question with your latest code and error message? This line works fine for me on both Python 2 and Python 3.